# Redirect from server side in NextJS 13

Tags: next.js, http-redirect, next.js13

I am currently working on a nextjs 13 app where I am authenticating the user using firebase from the server side. The authentication is working, however I am trying to set up a redirect if no authentication has taken place to the login page. I am trying to do this on the layout, however I am unable to get the redirect to actually work. The layout should be running server side so I am not sure what I am missing.

The documentation I am following doesn't seem to clarify much either  https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/redirect

[image: Error shown in browser]

```js
    import '../styles/theme.scss';
    import Header from '@/components/header/header';
    import verifyCookie from '@/firebase/auth/verify';
    import {redirect} from 'next/navigation';

    export const metadata = {
      title: 'My website',
      description: 'This is a test website',
    }

    export default async function RootLayout({
      children,
    }: {
      children: React.ReactNode
    }) {
        const isValid = await verifyCookie('user');
        console.log(isValid);

        // code is going into here, but the redirect is not doing anything...
        if (!isValid) { 
          try {
            redirect("/login"); 
          }
          catch (e) {
            console.log("redirecting to /login");
          }
        }

      return (
        <html lang="en">
          <head>
            <meta charSet="utf-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
          </head>
          <body>
            
              <Header />
              {children}
       
          </body>
        </html>
      );
    }
```

Comment: are you able to log from inside the if statement block ?

Comment: the user is already logged in at this stage, I am merely getting the auth cookie (named 'user') and verifying it using firebase API. These steps are working, its only the redirect step that is not working

Comment: Yeah I know I mean did you verify if the code enters inside the if block or not try to colsone.log inside the if statement and after it

Comment: I have added a screenshot to show the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Nextj13 as you can see [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/42556)

according to [timneutkens](https://github.com/timneutkens) Co-author of Next.js

> This is currently expected, handling certain cases of redirect() as server-side redirects is not implemented yet, general recommendation for that right now is using middleware.

commented on Nov 7, 2022

but it seems the issue still occures, you can try to use the lastest version as I understood this may solve the problem or at least it will make you able to redirect but you'll still get the error.

there are some alternatives you can try too like [this one](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/42556#issuecomment-1431356723)

Comment: It's fixed https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/47345


`import { redirect } from "next/navigation";`
`redirect('/redirect-url')`

Answer (score 4):

From NextJS 14 onward, if you want to redirect user from server side component, you can use `redirect()`.

import it from 'next/navigation' package

```
import { redirect } from "next/navigation"
```

and pass the url parameter to it

```
redirect(url);
```

To redirect from client side component, one can always use `useRouter()`. It can be imported from 'next/navigation' package.

```
import { useRouter} from "next/navigation"

const router = useRouter();
```

you can use `router.push(url)` to redirect user to desired path.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Hatana's response. It apears to be a bug, and de state os the fix for it is confuse for me. Now, on version 13.4.7, I still have this problem with redirect function on layout.

In my case, I am verifying if user is authenticated on the Root layout because I provide user info to a React context on this layout, then I use the same information to redirect from there. There are other soluctions for this case, but i tested and work using a Redirect component:

```js
'use client';

import { useEffect } from 'react';

import LinearProgress from '@mui/material/LinearProgress';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

export function Redirect({ to }: { to: string }) {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    router.replace(to);
    router.refresh();
  });

  return <LinearProgress />;
}
```

The component redirects and shows a Loading from MUI while do that, but you can remove it.

When the component renders, the user is redirected, then you can render it conditionally in yut component.

Answer (score 0):

wrap redirect all in a `async` function. For eg.:

```
const logOutUser = async () => {
  redirect("/login");
};
```

works in next version 14.0.4